# Are cherry blossoms ever used in cooking for their flavor? Is there a preference between ornamental and agricultural varieties?

Tags: flavor, flowers

I've recently asked in Biology SE [What makes cherry blossoms so delicious? Does this delicious molecule (or molecules) have some function in the blossom? Does saliva activate it?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/114094/27918) It begins

> My friend showed me a news item about a monkey (or macaque) recently (early February) seen in Taiwan eating cherry blossoms. I assumed it must have been eating caterpillars or other insects that eat the blossoms, but a quick search in google found a related video shot in Japan [Monkey Eating Cherry Blossoms in Slow Motion](https://youtu.be/1beZGlaWOvU).
>
> So a few days ago I tried a few. I pulled off the petals (since the monkey also seemed uninterested in them) and when I first started chewing I tasted nothing but inert vegetable matter.
>
> But then over about 15 to 20 seconds of chewing the little blossom bodies I noticed it first became bitter, then slowly increasing taste of what I describe as "Black Cherry" flavor, but without any sweetness. It continued to get stronger and more delicious, and I did not want to stop!
>
> That day I'd chewed (and eventually swallowed) about a dozen blossoms and felt absolutely wonderful; like I had been treated to a real delicacy.
>
> **note:** The cherry trees planted and cultiated for their decorative blossoms in the early spring are not the same as the trees that yield commercial cherries. I'm told their fruit is quite sour.

**Question:** Are cherry blossoms ever used in cooking for their flavor? Is there a preference between ornamental (those valued for their blossoms) and agricultural (valued for their fruit) varieties?

---

[image: decorative cherry blossoms in Taipei in early February]

[image: decorative cherry blossoms in Taipei in early February]

Comment: I saw a travel TV show where someone had gone to a distillery that had made a Sakura vodka.  (They said a nearby place spread out tarps to catch the falling blossoms overnight, and they had to use them immediately each morning). Searching online suggests that more than one distillery is producing something similar

Comment: @Joe there's gin as well

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be quite widely used as a flavouring.

Cherry blossom [*extract*](https://msk-ingredients.com/msk-1638-cherry-blossom-natural-flavour-drops-water-soluble-30ml) is certainly sold, as is [syrup for cocktails](https://www.discountcoffee.co.uk/products/william-fox-cherry-blossom-flavouring-cocktail-syrup-750ml?variant=40196878368855&currency=GBP&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google%2Bshopping&nis=5) (not that I've tried either).  I suspected that the blossom might be used in a similar way to rosewater or orange blossom water,  which led me to finding liquid extracts, but under the name [Sakura* powder](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sakura-Japanese-Blossoms-leaves-Aromatic/dp/B09QYJC1SF?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&psc=1&smid=AH8SVFNRWTKAQ) it's also sold in powdered form (apparently that's actually powdered petals).

If you're in the US, you can buy [cherry blossom flavoured sparkling water](https://www.target.com/p/lacroix-cherry-blossom-sparkling-water-8pk-12-fl-oz-cans/-/A-85756147) in Target (naturally flavoured apparently).

The whole blossoms are sometimes used as a cocktail garnish as well, either candied or salted, according to a [bartender's recipe guide](https://www.diffordsguide.com/encyclopedia/1651/cocktails/bartenders-guide-to-foraging-cherry-blossom), which has plenty of further suggestions for use.

Note that not all cherry-like *prunus* species have edible flowers, but those cultivated for their blossom tend to, as do varieties cultivated for fruit (but if you pick the blossom you won't get any fruit).  Even ornamental cherries [are known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_blossom#Toxicity) to contain a rather mild toxin, [coumarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coumarin), which is also found in cassia cinnamon, and is reduced by the traditional processing of sakura.

Plum blossom (also *prunus* species) is also used in making tea and flavouring food.  Some related species also have toxic parts, including the cherry laurels.

---

* Sakura is the Japanese word for cherry blossom.

Comment: I wish this had come up about 20 years ago, when I had a cherry tree but always lost the fruit to the birds.  I've just planted a rose in the hopes of making rosewater again, so I'd give it a try.

Comment: "Note that not all cherry-like *prunus* species have edible flowers..." suggests again (as did the answer in Biology SE) that I shouldn't go and just start munching any flower because it's initially biter taste improves as I keep chewing. I'm just curious if you came across any information about just how inedible they can get... could a dozen blossoms drop me in my tracks right there under the tree? Anyway, I will now go off and look for some cherry blossom extract and "wean myself" off of the blossoms themselves. :-)

Comment: @uhoh I didn't get anything much clearer than that from anything I read, except a hint that cherry laurel ([Prunus laurocerasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_laurocerasus) and closely related species) are probably to be avoided - but their flowers look quite different.  The common edible cherries as well as most ornamental ones seem to be in [*Prunus* subgenus *Cerasus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_subg._Cerasus).

Comment: ... I've found something worthy of an edit

Comment: Uups, I suddenly feel we may be unexpectedly busy so that the planned pruning of our ornamental cherry gets mysteriously delayed a bit longer. Probably until April. (Don‘t tell hubby!)

Comment: @Stephie you might want to read the links I just added to the answer before deciding whether you'd like to

Comment: Apparently the leaves of the sakura cherry are used to make "Sakura mochi" - looks like a salted leaf wrapped around a mochi, so the leaves are edible as well. I would guess strongly dependent on preparation as to how tasty. Salting will remove the bitter components probably.